# Change ArrayList<?> tag for each list element

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, tags

I have following method:

```
public String[][] launch(){

        String[][] result = new String[2][];

        for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){

            device.pressHome();
            ui.wait(500);
            ui.close();
            ui.close();
            ui.openProgram("ON");

            long TStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ui.detectContactList();
            long TStop = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float res = TStop - TStart;
            res /= 1000;
            ui.log("[loading time]: "+ res);

            ArrayList<String> attemptList = new ArrayList<String>();
            attemptList.add("Loading time");
            attemptList.add(Integer.toString(i));
            attemptList.add(Float.toString(res));
            result[i] = attemptList.toArray(new String[attemptList.size()]);
            System.out.println(attemptList);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

In the arraylist, I have tag - string, I want to change it to something another for each list element, that I add to it. How can I do this?

Comment: ArrayList<Object> u can insert any object

Comment: But if you need ArrayList<Object> you might've made some odd design choices. It's often avoidable, so think about it. And the phrase you're looking for is [generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: I need to learn how to create ArrayList<Object> - can you explain please or give me a link? I know that I need to create class Object, but I don't know how to make String type available to the ArrayList<Object>

Answer (score 1):

Two places you need to change.

Change

```
String[][] result = new String[2][];
```

to

```
Object[][] result = new Object[2][];
```

and

```
ArrayList<String> attemptList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<Object> attemptList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Add the elements like this

```
ArrayList<Object> attemptList = new ArrayList<Object>();
attemptList.add("Loading time");
attemptList.add(10);
attemptList.add(10f);
```

Finally you need to change your return type to `Object[][]`

Comment: It works - but I need to change tag <Object> to my own tag - <tagOne> for first list element and <tagTwo> for second ...etc. This list will be used with Xstream to create XML report - and I want to make differents tags in Array list to alias them with Xstrem

Comment: In case of this I need to create my own class that I will use in the ArrayList<myOwnClass> - I need to know how to create it